# How to integrate jrebel in arquillian tests on remote jboss testing?

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss-arquillian, jrebel

Testing java [persistence](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/#assumptions), want to integrate *jrebel* on *arquillian* tests. I've read something about an *arquillian jrebel* [extension](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-jrebel), but could not configure it well (maven dependency error).

Right now I'm just running remotely *Jboss* with *jrebel* plugin, on *pom.xml*:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
            <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is the above enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What maven plugin does is that it generates [rebel.xml](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel-reference-manual/app.html#app-3.1) configuration file. It is required to map the resources outside of the deployed application. The JVM itself should be started with a **-javaagent** argument (see the [manual](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel-reference-manual/server.html#server-4.6.1)). For Arquillian, there's a community contributed [extension](http://blog.itcrowd.pl/2012/04/arquillian-meets-jrebel.html), but I'm not sure how it actually works.